# C++ did not have the dp() function

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Tensorflow C++ API did not have the `dropout()` function. Which function can replace this `dropout()` function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always copy the algorithm from python ([link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L2335)).

```
random_tensor = keep_prob
random_tensor += random_ops.random_uniform(
    noise_shape, seed=seed, dtype=x.dtype)
# 0. if [keep_prob, 1.0) and 1. if [1.0, 1.0 + keep_prob)
binary_tensor = math_ops.floor(random_tensor)
ret = math_ops.div(x, keep_prob) * binary_tensor
```

Use `tensorflow::ops::RandomUniform` to get the random tensor with the right shape. The rest should be trivial.